# How to enable Animation programmatically in Android

Tags: android

When I used `overridePendingTransition` to translate from one activity to another activity it is working fine when `AllAnimations` are enable in `DisplaySettings` . But this Animation is not working when `AllAnimations` are disable . How to enable `AllAnimations` in `DisplaySettings`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can simply prompt people to start up the settings app so they can change it.

I don't think people will really want your app telling them the settings they choose themselves though. Just leave the animations, for the ones that actually want them and don't bother the ones that don't.

Comment: Thanks for your repally. But in Flipboard application animation is working fine even though animation is disable

Comment: Then my guess would be they do not use the standard methods to override transitions, but just have some custom Activity so the system doesn't recognize it as transition